# WPF Binding to TextBlock does not update target immediately

Tags: wpf, binding

I don't think my question falls into any others here already so hopefully somebody can assist me.

I have a TextBlock binding set up using INotifyPropertyChnaged and it does work. The problem i am having is when it updates the target control (the TextBlock)

A quick run down of my code

```
namespace XYZ
{
    public partial class Loading : Window
    {
        StatusMessage msg = StatusMessage.GetInstance();

        public loading()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = msg;
        }

        private void LoadBackEndUsers()
        {

            msg.Status = "Loading Users";

            //txtStatus.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
            //lblLoading.Focus();
            this.txtStatus.DataContext = msg;

            beUsers = new BackendUsers(Database);
            allBEUsers = beUsers.GetAllUsers();
        }

        private void LoadProducts()
        {
            msg.Status = "Loading Products";

            //txtStatus.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
            //lblLoading.Focus();
            this.txtStatus.DataContext = msg;

            products = new Product(Database);
            allProducts = products.GetAllProducts();
         }

         private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {           
             LoadBackEndUsers();          
             LoadProducts();
         }
    }
}
```

Now my issue is that my textblock displays "Loading Products" only after the method LoadProducts() is completed. It doesn't show "Loading Users" at all, so the target is only updating after everything has completed.

How do I get it to update immediately. The commented out bits was me just trying various things to try to force an update.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Neill

Comment: Not that this will fix your problem, but if your binding is truly working properly, I don't think you should have to reset the DataContext of this.txtStatus everytime you change msg.

Comment: yeah, was actually just using that to try to force an update for testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your retrieving of data is occurring on the same thread as your UI logic. This means that even though you change a property value and raise the OnPropertyChanged it is not re-evaluated until after your blocking data access is done. Instead you should use a BackgroundWorker. Here is a great article that walks through how you can use this:

http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/

Comment: tx Matt, I figured it was something like that, will check out the the link as see what I can come up with

Comment: Hi Matt, Tx for that link. Went with the background worker as i have more control over whats going on. Working very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Your `StatusMessage` class should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.):</strike>

**Edit** : Im pretty sure that your `Window_ContentRendered` eventhanler blocks every UI update. I wrote a little sample that works for me:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  StatusMessage msg = new StatusMessage();
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = msg;
  }

  private void LoadBackEndUsers()
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => msg.Status = "Loading Users"), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
        //Load users here:
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => msg.Status = "Users loaded"), DispatcherPriority.Normal);

        // If users loaded start load products:
        LoadProducts();
      });
  }

  private void LoadProducts()
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => msg.Status = "Loading Products"), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
      //Load products here:
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => msg.Status = "Products Loaded"), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
    });
  }

  private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    LoadBackEndUsers();
    //LoadProducts();
  }
}
```

Comment: "I have a TextBlock binding set up using INotifyPropertyChnaged and it does work. The problem i am having is when it updates the target control (the TextBlock)" - I did say this and i did mention the binding works, i just don't know why it doesn't update immediately after a set msg.Status = "blah";

Comment: @Neil Ok i need to go to a doctor to check my eyes. :D Sorry.

Comment: no probs, and sorry for my somewhat volatile response, this is just driving me nuts!

Comment: @Neil Edited my answer. I hope it will help you out.

Comment: tx Ben, will check it out a bit later tonight and let you know

Comment: Hi Ben, gave your code a test and it does seem to be working. Gonna try to tweak it a bit. Thanks a million. Will keep you updated.

Comment: Hey Ben, your code works, but in the end went with the background worker. Thanks for all your input

Comment: Neil Im glad that finally you got a working solution, but don't forget to accept a question as a solution.